# Interlocked hanging game?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, interlocked

Just attempting to use `Interlocked.Increment(ref threads)` and it just hangs my game.

```
public static int threads;

...

Interlocked.Increment(ref threads);
```

Using `System.Threads` also.

I've moved it into the main thread and out of it, can't seem to get it to work anywhere. Is this just Unity causing this?

Comment: Please reference your game technology, are you using XNA or stuff like that?

Comment: Just unity. using UnityEngine; It's a unity project. Unity is an engine designed for game development. C#

Comment: Oh... I know Unity as an [IoC container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx). I guess this is a totally different thing.

Comment: Yes Definitely a different thing all together. I'll sepcify that. .

Comment: Trying searching for usages of the 'threads' variable, you might find some suspicious code

Comment: Don't forget that threads are not a trivial thing in Unity3d. You have to be careful not to interfere with the rendering loop, updates etc.

Comment: And that statement replaced what? An increment of the `threads` variable, like `threads++;`? I can't imagine `Interlocked.Increment` causing a hang. Are you certain that's the source of your problem?

Comment: Unity seems to be weird with threads here. Anything to do with XDocument also causes issues where it just kills the threads. Dunno why, was trying to make loading faster. May not be able to now.

Also yes it replaced threads++. when i commented it out, the hang stopped. I think it's just Unity not liking threading.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net `Interlocked.Increment` doesn't actually lock anything (at least it definitely doesn't for an `int`); it only ensures the increment happens atomically.

Either it is not actually the change causing your problem or you've got another `Interlocked` imported into your namespaces.

Comment: It's the only interlocked I have and I also tried to lock before I used it. Still hangs.

Comment: A minor point: if you lock, you almost definitely don't need Interlocked as well.